# Exclude pyc files from spotlight results (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, mac, python, spotlight

How should I go about disabling specific files with extensions .pyc from showing up in my quick spotlight search results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide them using `chflags` in Terminal:

```
chflags hidden filename.pyc
```

I thought they're hidden by default though.

Comment: It shows up in the Documents category.